# Is it possible to disable an action in pre-dispatch?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-controller

In my controller I have a preDispatch method where I check if the user is logged in. If he is not I redirect the user to login form.

Is there any way to disable one of the action's from the preDispatch method? Because I do not need the authorisation for this action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the plugin, you can check if that specific controller and action is being called and allow the request to continue.

Something similar to the following in your plugin will work.

```
public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) {
    // ...

    $controller = $request->getControllerName();
    $action     = $request->getActionName();

    if ($controller == 'login' && $action == 'login') {
        return ; // do not execute any more plugin code
    }

    // deny access and redirect to login form
```

Comment: tanks a lot that was what I need:)

Answer (score 0):

I usually use my "Empty" controller/action to do this :

```
public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) {
if (!$logined){
 $request->setControllerName('empty')->setActionName('index');
return;
}
}
```

It substitute your current action.